# if and else statement java

Tags: java

I am literally new at java and struggling with a part 
so I am suppose to set an option to set new price in a car rental program

```
public class CarToBuy extends CAR {
    private int price;
    private int registration_Year;
    private int milage;
    private boolean sold;

    public CarToBuy(String Description, int cost, int year, int miles) {
        super(Description);
        price = cost;
        registration_Year = year;
        milage = miles;
        sold = false;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getReg() {
        return registration_Year;
    }

    public int getMilage() {
        return milage;
    }

    public void setNewPrice(int newprice) {
        price = newprice;
        if (sold = false) {
            System.out.println("car not in stock");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The New price is" + newprice);
        }
    }

    public void carBuying(String Customer_name) {

        if (sold = false) {
            System.out.println("The Car is not in stock");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Thank you purchasing" + Customer_name);
        }
    }
}
```

even though the user get a display message "the car is not in stock" the price gets updates however what I am trying to do is that the price does not change if the car is not in stock 
so if false = price does not changes
if true price changes

Comment: `sold = false` should be `sold == false`

Comment: Or even better `if (!sold)`

Comment: @Héctor That's complete alternative way. I'm trying to correct his mistake.

Comment: Of course, you're right, I didn't want to sound rude...

Comment: @anjum khan: Please stop vandalizing your question.

Comment: I want to delete it but unable to do so, because when i submit it will be considered as plagiarism

Answer (score 1):

It looks like if condition is wrong. No need to compare boolean variable in if condition. 
Try to change below code

```
if (sold = false){
....
}
```

with

```
if(!sold){
....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The operator **=** assigns a value to a variable whilst **==** is used as a conditional operator.

So;

```
if(sold){
System.out.println("Thank you purchasing" + Customer_name);
} else {
System.out.println("The Car is not in stock")
}
```

This will execute the first block of code if *sold* is true and the other block otherwise.

Comment: thank you makes more sense i was assigning ! understand now